# Virtual pair of COM port in docker container

Tags: windows, docker, serial-port

I'm trying to find the way to create the pair of COM ports inside my container (the base is microsoft/windowsservercore).

As far as I know I have to find MSI installer of such software to perform silence installation. But still I have to create exact COM devices via UI and it's not an option for docker container.

Is the any other options to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like i finally found the solution. It's name - com0com. 
That program has silent installation and also command line for terminal-way COM list configuration.

http://com0com.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/com0com/com0com/ReadMe.txt?revision=RELEASED